# How to sketch a function which is 2 to the power of x

Tags: functions

Hi I'm looking for help to sketch a function.

$$
(e)\quad Sketch\quad the\quad graphs\quad of\quad each\quad of\quad the\quad following\quad functions:\\ (i)\quad f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\quad given\quad by\quad f\left( x \right) ={ 2 }^{ x }\\ (ii)\quad g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\quad given\quad by\quad g\left( x \right) ={ 2 }^{ x }
$$

Since its ${2}^{x}$ how do I graph that can someone help.

Comment: It is $2$ to the power of $x$, not $2x$

Comment: It is 2 to the power of $x$. Try to consider another expression for $2^x$, using exponential and logarithm. And then using the graph of $exp(x)$, you should get your answer. Question b) is just a discrete version of a)

Comment: What other expression do you mean? Can you think of one?

Comment: Look here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#The_exponential_function

If you look for it yourself you will remember it better :)
"The natural logarithm is the inverse of the exponential function"

Comment: Here are some things you should consider: What is the difference between the graph of part (i) and that of part (ii)? How do you graph a function in general? What are some specific values of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a function simply takes a value and assigns it exactly one another value. Now find some graphing paper or sketch out a cartesian ($xy$) plane. I'd start with part $(ii)$ of the assignment. Take the smallest integer in $\Bbb{N}$ (could be $0$ or $1$ depending on what you prefer) but I'll assume $1$ for the sake of the answer. Then evaluate $g(1) = 2^1 = 2$. Now put a point on the coordinate $(1,2)$. Then move to $x = 2$ and evaluate $g(2) = 2^2 = 4$. Now put a point on the coordinate $(2,4)$. Proceed in this fashion until you have few coordinates plotted on your plane. That's it.

Now for part $(i)$ copy exactly what you did for part $(ii)$, except that you're going to draw a smooth line that connects all the dots (we connect the dots because the domain and range of your function is $\Bbb{R}$, and it would be ridiculous to attempt to evaluate $f$ at every single point in $\Bbb{R}$. We must infer what the curve will look like from a few other values of $f$) You may now also include the coordinate $(0,1)$ if you didn't already. You should also evaluate $f$ at $-1$, $-2$ etc. until have have a couple coordinates plotted with negative $x$ values. Then continue drawing your smooth line from the right half of the plane to connect the dots on the left half of the plane.